# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException en matriz

Tags: java

Estoy intentando mostrar los datos de una matriz que estan en la clase principal MAIN y las cantidades se encuentran en el metodo CARGAl, en un metodo aparte, pero sale el error del tituto, y resalta que el problema es en la linea que muestra los datos en el metodo MOSTRAR DATOS. Soy nuevo con este lenguaje y no tengo idea del porque pasa esto. Antes no utilizaba metodos e iba con normalidad, ahora que si no entiendo porque no logra utilizarlos.

```
package com.company;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main {

Scanner ENTRADA = new Scanner(System.in);
int CD = 1;
String[][] DATOS;


public void CARGA(){
    DATOS= new String[5][2];

    System.out.println("BIENVENIDO");
    System.out.println("Programa de Elder Vielman");
    System.out.println("==================================================");
    System.out.println();

    for(int F=0;F<5;F++) {
        System.out.println("EMPLEADO" +CD+":");
        System.out.print(" - NOMBRE: ");
        DATOS[F][0]=ENTRADA.nextLine();
        System.out.print(" - CORREO: ");
        DATOS[F][1]=ENTRADA.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        CD = CD+1;
    }
}

public void MOSTRARDATOS(){
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("DATOS");
    System.out.printf("");

    CD = 0;
    System.out.printf("%-6s%-15s%-15s\n","No.","NOMBRE","CORREO");
    for(int F=0;F<5;F++) {
        System.out.printf("%-6s%-15s%-15s\n",CD,DATOS[F][0],DATOS[F][1]);
        CD = CD+1;
    }
    System.out.printf("");
    Main SECTOR = new Main();
    SECTOR.MENU();
    System.out.printf("");
    System.out.printf("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main SECTOR = new Main();
    SECTOR.CARGA();
    SECTOR.MENU();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Muestra el error - stackTrace, p.ej, y el método **menu**.

Comment: ¿Para que creas un objeto nuevo de tipo Main? no lo necesitas, llama directamente a los métodos (solo tendrás que ponerle el static a estos). Luego en el main, llamas a `menu()` pero no hay ningún método llamado `menu`  ¿por que en `mostrarmenu() vuelves a crear otro objeto main? por lo que mas quieras, sigue las convenciones de nombres de variables y métodos.